# Can Windows Server 2012 run as a guest VM under Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V Host?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

Can Windows Server 2012 run as a guest virutal machine under a Windows Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V host?  If so, are there any important or notable restrictions on what the guest OS can do running in this scenario?

I've got a lab PC with lots of VMs running as guests on a W2K8R2 Hyper-V server.  I don't do anything too exotic with the VMs, basically just running tests of my application software installations.  I'd be looking for IIS, COM+ and general WinForms installation functionality.

Can I create a Windows Server 2012 guest VM to run in my environment or do I need to upgrade my lab PC to run Server 2012 Hyper-V in order to support a Server 2012 guest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2737297) it is possible but may thow some warning messages here and there.

Comment: Thanks(+1) - That is a helpful KB, insofar as it tells you that the whole thing is out of the question (the way running 2K8 on 2K5 was).  I've already got Windows 8 VM guests working fine.  There were hiccups until the integration was installed (as per the KB).

Answer (score 7):

You could try this:

**An update that enables Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 to be hosted in a Hyper-V virtual machine on Windows Server 2008 R2**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2526776

Edit: hotfix 2526776 has been superseded by a newer hotfix:

**You cannot run a Windows 8-based or Windows Server 2012-based virtual machine in Windows Server 2008 R2**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2744129

Comment: Thanks for the KB link (+1).  It didn't turn out that I needed this hotfix (not yet at least!) but it's good to know that the KB is there should I run into trouble.